# Jingle on Android and XMPP

Tags: android

We are trying to build a PTT (push to talk) app. The idea is to send an audio file over the air from one device to another. Is Jingle the only logical choice, if so does anyone have any pointers on how to get this setup in an Android environment? + XMPP Or is there a better solution?

Worse case scenario I was thinking of having a C2DM push notification fly from one device to another and with every push payload notify the device where the audio file is on the server and have that unit stream the audio file, but it seems too flaky to do it this way, since the push notifications may not always be guaranteed, or it might take some time till it reaches the device, etc. The idea here is to have a real live experience and as fast as possible.

Any help is kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this suits for PushToTalk, but for realtime is really simple and usable. Draft of [Jingle Nodes Setup Guide](https://docs.google.com/present/edit?id=0AYRjaHIDbVEcZG52cmd3N180NzVrc201Z2JmYw&hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the Jingle Nodes Standard. That way, not only can a user of your server talk to each other, but they could talk to other existing clients on the desktop and on other platforms.